# OpenLayers Source - how to get Attributions

Tags: openlayers, attribution

Using OpenLayers 0.6.5, I want to be able to copy the attributions from one source, and set the same value for the attributions of another source.  But I can't find any way to extract the attributions from a source.  I'm testing with the simplest case - an OSM source.

```js
var origSource = new ol.source.OSM();
console.log(origSource.attributions);
```

Just logs "Undefined".

I've tried a few other variations, such as `origSource.get('attributions');`, but I can't find any method that works.  There does not appear to be any `getAttributions()` method either.

Is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: There is an undocumented `getAttributions()`  method which returns a function, and calling the function `getAttributions()()` returns an array of attributions.  Some sources (e.g. Bing) expect the function to have a `frameState` parameter, but most do not.

Comment: @Mike This deserves to be put into answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an undocumented `getAttributions()` method which returns a function, and calling the function `getAttributions()()` returns an array of attributions. Some sources (e.g. Bing) expect the function to have a `frameState` parameter, but most do not.

The function itself can also be used as an attribution [https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Source.html#~AttributionLike](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Source.html#%7EAttributionLike) for another source.

Comment: This works!  Thanks for pointing this one out to me.